# vb.net error "startindex cannot be larger than length of string" I reversed text direction when typing in a textbox from ltr, to rtl

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I have been having an error saying "startindex cannot be larger than length of string"
I reversed text direction when typing in a textbox from left to right.. to right to left. Backspace is supposed to delete texts on the left of the blinking cursor, but since we changed the text direction, we want backspace to delete what is on the left side of the blinking cursor instead.
For example... when I entered four numbers, 4321 then i moved the cursor in the middle of 3 and 2 then I press backspace three times, it generates the said error.here is our code [here is our error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsinC.png) and here is our code

```
  Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(8) Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
        Dim sText As String = tb.Text
        Dim iSel_Start_Pos As Int64
        If sText.Length > 0 Then
            If tb.SelectionStart = 0 Then
                sText = sText.Substring(1)
                iSel_Start_Pos = 0
            Else
                sText = sText.Substring(0, tb.SelectionStart) & _
                        sText.Substring(tb.SelectionStart + 1)
                iSel_Start_Pos = tb.SelectionStart
            End If
        End If
        tb.Text = sText
        tb.SelectionStart = iSel_Start_Pos
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

    If TextBox3.SelectionStart > 0 Then
        TextBox3.SelectionStart = TextBox3.SelectionStart - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: do yo guys use debugger at all?

Comment: @T.S. why debug when there is Stackoverflow?  http://i.imgur.com/eMijkJj.jpg